# how to hide the key in url,but not the values using Get method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, url, key-value, modelattribute

I am getting the Model Attribute Object's, Key and value pair in the url,I have to hide those key-value pair or else it should be values alone.

Ex:consider the following url,

```
http://localhost:8080/Sample/showPage.htm?
```

> name=ram&std=II&sec=A

```
&Search=Get
```

this name,std and sec forms the model attribute object 'StudentDetails' pojo class,I want the url like below:

```
 http://localhost:8080/Sample/showPage.htm?
```

> ram/II/A/Get

Comment: Which version of spring you are using ?

Comment: So you want to generate RESTful URLs?

Comment: Am using Spring 3.1.2,yes i want to generate RESTful url's.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Controller`, assuming that you have a method call `showPage`

Use the following,

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}/{std}/{sec}/{Search}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showPage(@PathVariable("name") String name,@PathVariable("std") String std,
                          @PathVariable("sec") String sec,@PathVariable("Search") String Search) throws Exception {        
        // use the values name, std, sec and search as you need.     
        }
```

Comment: This is to read the RESTful url's but i want to form the RESTful url's.